# Bank will not take check

Tags: california

I am trying to liquidate everything to escape the coming market collapse. I went to the bank with a 600k check and they refused to deposit it. It exceeds the fdic limit.

Do I have any legal recourse? How do I get my money to a checking account before the market totally collapses?

Comment: Where does the 600k check comes from? Maybe whoever issued it will give a few smaller checks instead?

Comment: Comes from broker. Smaller checks dont affect it.

Comment: How do you know smaller checks don't affect it? How small are the checks that you have had refused?

Comment: Why can't your broker hold on to your money but just invest it in something extremely conservative, or hang on to it as "cash reserves"?

Answer (score 5):

The bank has the legal right to refuse to do business with you. There are exceptions but "wanting to deposit 600k" is not a protected class.

The FDIC limit is 250k. Since the bank has chosen not to accept deposits larger than that, you need to split it across multiple banks or find a bank willing to take it.

Comment: If you need to deposit 600k and literally only one bank exists, yes.

Comment: @JDjdj You'll probably get more help on money.stackexchange. Better still, consider paying an accountant to help

Comment: go to another bank.  A bank that won't take your money is an odd bank.  Also, if you think there is an upcoming market collapse, possible uninsured bank deposits isn't the best solution.  If the bank fails, your money would be lost.

Comment: @TigerGuy I don't even want to go into the logic behind putting everything in a single bank as a way to deal with an economic collapse.